# SQL Server Repeat number of rows based upon value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a record which has following structure,

```
Item      ActiveFrom         ActiveTo
 A        1/01/2015           25/12/2018
```

I have a Where Condition with Year Value . So whenever i apply a year value ,the records active on that year should be obtained.

for ablove Structure I did,

```
Select Item,YEAR(ActiveFrom) From Test
UNION 
Select Item,YEAR(ActiveTo) From Test
```

So i get two line items as below,

```
Item    Year
A        2015
A        2018
```

Now when i Apply where Clause as 2017 this records are not fetched ,so i need output like below,

```
Item    Year
A        2015
A        2016
A        2017
A        2018
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Please explain weather you want all years or just that you want after where clause also you only want year 2015 and 2018?

Comment: How are you applying the where? Aren't you doing it only for one of the date columns?

Comment: I want the records to get repeated for years it has been active

Comment: I have created the statement as a view so whenever i execute Select * from View Where Year=2018 it returns all the record active in that year.

Answer (score 0):

Join with a calendar table:

```
WITH years AS (
    SELECT 2015 AS year UNION ALL
    SELECT 2016 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2018
)

SELECT
    t.Item,
    c.year
FROM years c
INNER JOIN Test t
    ON c.year BETWEEN YEAR(t.ActiveFrom) AND YEAR(t.ActiveTo);
```